# Setting email reminders

Tags: scheduled-reminders

I would like to be able to set email reminders for individual actions to be completed on a set date/time.  Can I set these via customer records so that I receive an email reminder on the date I specify?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Scheduled Reminders (accessed via the Admin menu) to link an email reminder to an activity that you set up in the contact's record.

Or you could set up CiviCase to create a workflow if you want a series of connected actions/emails